# Recipient calculation in verifyTransactionBytes for Ardor

Tags: ardor

I'm trying to add `verifyTransactionBytes` to my app.  I am currently stuck because of `transaction.recipient !== data.recipient`.  I don't understand how `transaction.recipient` will ever equal `data.recipient`.

`data.recipient` equals `ARDOR-64L4-C4H9-Z9PU-9YKDT`

However,  `transaction.recipient` equals `12686039152117651770352583052021228896653772998482022211948610002430512793010043372255281183988421160450227631016638876582933743874739812608892576232835541561180017189881475915550182092483428449468438018195304514943626747005224233901130236596723251118266281272406204049816147466250586545776300564249483796886483621200942491492199171631589798205980673`

This doesn't really surprise me, because I don't see how an ARDOR address gets generated from `transaction.recipient = String(helpers.byteArrayToBigInteger(byteArray, pos));`

Which looks like it should return a number, not a string.  What am I missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either convert data.recipient from RS format to numeric format or convert transaction.recipient from numeric format to RS format using NRS.convertNumericToRSAccountFormat(id)

Comment: So transaction.recipient should be the numeric format of the recipient addresses?

Comment: Right, you can convert the public key to numeric account then convert it to RS format using NRS.convertNumericToRSAccountFormat(id)

Comment: I found my error.  My `byteArrayToBigInteger` function was incorrect.  Your answer helped me though, as I new what outcome I should expect with the numeric address.  Thank you!